# How to validate third party server urls in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hystrix

Actually in my Hybris application I am using different third party servers ,So I want to validate the third party URLS that its responding or not.So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Cron Job for it.

In hac you can run script. Example groovy script below:

```
URL url = new URL("http://mkysoft.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int httpCode = connection.getResponseCode();
return "Http code: " + httpCode;
```

Comment: I wanted to validate it manually,Like getting the urls and checking whether its responding back or not.

Comment: you can run groovy/binshell script in hac.